# Подключение объявлений о недвижимости к картам и отображение объявлений на карте по фильтру С# WINDOWS FORMS

Tags: c#, winforms, api

В рамках курсового проекта необходимо сделать поиск недвижимости и отображение на карте. С картами разобрался и реализовал поиск по адресу. Теперь мне необходимо исходя из фильтра отправлять запрос и отображать недвижимость на карте с информацией об этой недвижимости. В основном в интернете вся информация на других языках и нужную информацию получить не удалось. Как необходимо формировать этот запрос и указывать в нем параметры моего фильтра?  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос в чем? Не удалось - сожалеем, но это не вопрос.

Comment: Отправлять запрос куда? Даже если вопрос появился, то какой ожидается ответ? "Напишите программу с нуля"? Или нужно помочь с реализацией какого-то метода? Есть пример кода? (пусть даже неработающего) Видите, у меня больше вопросов, чем у вас. Поэтому отвечать пока вам, а не мне. :)

Comment: Мне необходимо отправлять запрос к сервесу яндекс недвижимости : https://realty.yandex.ru/ramenskoe/kupit/kvartira/1,2-komnatnie/karta/ . Мне необходимо понять, как реализовать этот запрос с помощью кода и как передать параметры фильтра в этот запрос. Код у меня есть только для поиска по картам

Comment: чтоб что-то запрашивать нужно иметь доступ к api, а у вас есть такой доступ? Что-то я не нашел открытого публичного api по яндекс недвижимости. Дадите ссылочку?

Comment: Может вы мне нормально объясните и не будете тут умничать? Может можно к каким-то другим сервисам недвижимости обратиться и решить данную задачу

Comment: Извините, я думал в в теме, раз взялись за такой проект. Что такое Web API,  post запрос, get запрос, JSON вы в курсе?

Comment: Только читал об этом, поэтому и прошу помощи тут. В учебном заведении я это не изучал и мне сказали ищите решения и разбирайтесь сами. Запрос по поиску адреса я сделал, а как это сделать с недвижимостью с параметрами фильтра я не совсем понимаю

Comment: А как вы делает запрос по адресу? Вы же работаете через API яндекс карт, как я понял или нет?

Comment: Использую GMap.NET. Там у меня выбраны яндекс карты.

Comment: Понятно. Дело в том что эта библиотека берет информацию через запросы к [api яндекс карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/) и такая возможность существует потому, что этот api общедоступен. С недвижимостью история совсем другая, открытого для всех api яндекс не предоставляет. Можно попробовать поискать какие-то другие сервисы. Хотя, я сомневаюсь, что вы найдете бесплатно открытые реальные данные по недвижимости - тема недвижимости горячая и халявного доступа к актуальной информации в отрытом доступе вы вряд ли найдете.

Comment: Тогда как мне вообще решить эту задачу? Может есть какие-то другие способы? В управлении пакетов NuGet есть пакет Yandex.Api. Он мне никак не поможет?

Comment: Сорян, не знаю. Ищите, мне попадались источники с платным собственным api, которые воруют или собирают данные с разных сайтов по недвижимости. Или сами пишите какой-нибудь парсер на какой-нибудь сайт недвижимости. Яндекс брать не советую, там жестко отслеживают такую деятельность и блокируют.

Comment: Как вариант еще, подойти к преподу и объяснить ситуацию и либо поменять тему, либо сделать фиктивные запросы к абстрактному api с готовыми результатами, чисто для демонстрации работы программы.